# How to block ads using WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest

Tags: android, webview

I usualy use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to block ads in webview, but this time, the ads links in a new website doesn't captured in

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

and

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

but it captured in

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url)
```

so, i used this method

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("soidfzs", url);
                WebResourceResponse webResourceResponse = null;
                if (url.contains("https://googleads") || url.contains("doubleclick") || url.contains("google-analytics.com") || url.contains("adservice") || url.contains("securepubads")) {
                    Log.d("soidfzs", "here");
                    return webResourceResponse;
                } else {
                    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
                }

            }
```

but, links still loading and ads showing

So, what should i return ?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `webResourceResponse` which you set to `null` prior to your if statement where you check whether the request might be for an ad.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) for `shouldInterceptRequest` however states:

```java
* @return A {@link android.webkit.WebResourceResponse} containing the
*         response information or {@code null} if the WebView should load the
*         resource itself.
```

So in returning `null`, you are telling the WebViewClient to load the resource itself, i.e., fulfil the ad request and load the ad.

In order to let the request slide and return your own value, you have to return your own `WebResourceResponse` instance **which must not be null** for this to work.

```java
return new WebResourceResponse(
        "text/html",
        "UTF-8",
        null
);
```

Here, I set the `mimeType` (first argument) to `"text/html"`, although it could probably also be something else, like `"text/plain"`.

I set the second argument—`encoding`—to `"UTF-8"`(same as before: could probably be something else).

And now for the most important part: I set `data`, the third argument, to `null`.

This results in the WebView getting a valid `WebResourceResponse` instance which is not `null` but has no data which in turn results in nothing loading.

**Be aware** that this will trigger `WebViewClient#onReceivedError` as the WebView client essentially couldn’t load anything. This is not a problem per se, but something to look out for in case you override `onReceivedError`.